# How do I update an HTML class from a CometActor

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, lift

In response to some asynchronous event on the server, I want to update the class of an HTML node in order to reflect its updated status.  I know the id of the node, and the class I want to change it to.  What JsCmd do I need to use to update the class?  In general, where can I find a good reference on the JsCmd's and what they do?

A simple example:

```
case class UpdateClass(id: String, htmlClass: String)

class ClassUpdater extends CometActor {
  override def lowPriority: scala.PartialFunction[scala.Any, scala.Unit] = {
    case UpdateClass(id, htmlClass) =>
      partialUpdate(Noop /* now what? */)
  }

  def render = NodeSeq.Empty
}
```

So if I had the HTML:

```
<html><body>
<lift:comet type="ClassUpdater"/>
<div id="foo" class="bar">insert text here</div>
</body></html>
```

If I sent the message `UpdateClass("foo", "baz")` to my `ClassUpdater`, I want the class of my `div` to change to `baz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** *I’ve found a better way to do it. The old code is now more of a blueprint for more complicated stuff.*

Looks like there is a more straightforward way of doing it without jQuery:

```
SetElemById("foo", JE.Str("baz"), "className")
```

which translates to a JavaScript call

```
document.getElementById("foo").className = "baz";
```

Note that `JE.Str("baz")` can be any `JsExp` and if you could also do something like

```
SetElemById("foo", JE.Str("baz"), "firstChild", "className")
```

which would change the class of the first child. (See: [SetElemById](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds/SetElemById.html))

You can have a look at the code for the [JsCMD](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.1/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmd.html) trait for what else is possible with build-in commands.

---

In case you want to something more complicated, however, something like this might help you. It sends a jQuery command which will change the class in `#oldId` to `newClass`.

```
  case class ChangeClassAtId(oldId: String, newClass: String) extends JsCmd {
    def toJsCmd = """try {
      $(""" + ("#" + oldId).encJs + """).attr("class", """ + newClass.encJs + """);
    } catch (e) {}"""
  }
```

Changing all occurrences of a class everywhere is a bit more complicated:

```
case class ChangeClass(oldClass: String, newClass: String) extends JsCmd {
    def toJsCmd = """try {
      $(""" + ("." + oldClass).encJs + """).each(function(){
          $(this).addClass(""" + newClass.encJs + """).removeClass(""" + oldClass.encJs + """);
        });
    } catch (e) {}"""
  }
```

You should use it instead of `Noop` of course.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - I misread the question. My answer merely updates the contents of the div.

Check out: http://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/examples/example/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/example/comet/Clock.scala

You'll want something like this:

case UpdateClass(id, htmlClass) =>
  partialUpdate(SetHtml(id, Text("TEXT TO SHOVE INTO DIV")))

Comment: But that only changes the content of an `id`.